# PID control: What does it mean that an ideal derivative term is not causal?

Tags: pid-controller

On Wikipedia, it says: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller

> An ideal derivative is not causal, so that implementations of PID
>   controllers include an additional low pass filtering for the
>   derivative term, to limit the high frequency gain and noise

Can someone explain in simple terms what does it mean for the derivative to not be "causal"? What is the implication of causality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Causality implies that the current system is only determined by the past state of the system - that is, a [causal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system) cannot depend on its future state.

Calculating the actual derivative requires knowing the state (infinitesimally) before and ***after*** the current moment. This need to define the derivative based on knowledge of the future violates causality. Approximations of the derivative must be used in a practical implementation of a PID controller.

Comment: To carry this line of reasoning a little further : that means the actual D term is always very slightly out of date, i.e. lagging. So high gain at high frequency would promote instability, therefore gain at high frequency must be limited. Or, because the D term is lagging, it must be low pass filtered to prevent instability.

Comment: Sorry but isn't a derivative defined by (y(t+h) - y(t))/h? You mentioned we need to know state before, but there isn't a y(t-h) term... Can you also clarify what you meant by approximation of the derivatives

Comment: Good point, @Lookbehindyou - by the definition of a derivative you don't need to know the past state (although one could argue that once you finish measuring the current state, the information has already become from the past...). As for approximations of derivatives, I just mean easy-to-implement schemes for guessing the true derivative. In a discretized system ("y" is reported in incremental values, like the output of an ADC), small "h" values tend to make the derivative appear huge. Averaging a few samples can get you close to the real derivative while avoiding these numerical issues.